# Fragment implementation - Using google's document as an example

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

I am reading google developer's article on Fragment implementation. I am stuck at one point in the session "[Creating event callbacks to the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks)".

It says that when Fragment A, which contains a list of articles' title, wants to communicate with Article Fragment, which shows the content of the article, Fragment A should implement an interface OnArticleSelectedListener. A listener is set in the activity hosting the two fragments, and the listener will send information to Article Fragment.

My problem is that, why don't we simply implement an interface in Article Fragment listening to Fragment A's selection? I know there must be a reason, but I just don't get it.

My Attempt:
Is it because we cannot find a reference to Article Fragment in Fragment A? We could only find the reference of Article Fragment from the hosting activity.

Many Thx.

Comment: It would be useful if you used the same names for classes as used in the article for better comprehension of your question. There is only FragmentA no FragmentB in the article.

Comment: Ok, I change it to article then.

Comment: Did you read this part ? 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments can not communicate  with each other. `Activity` is not only a Host but also acts as a middle man between two or more `fragments`.

(taken from developer.android.com)
Although a Fragment is implemented as an object that's independent from an Activity and can be used inside multiple activities, a given instance of a fragment is directly tied to the activity that contains it.

In some cases, you might need a fragment to share events with the activity. A good way to do that is to define a callback interface inside the fragment and require that the host activity implement it. When the activity receives a callback through the interface, it can share the information with other fragments in the layout as necessary.